# How do I insert time into my Maya animation timeline

Tags: animation, maya

I frequently get myself into trouble when I've put together a complex animation in Maya with lots of rigs and connections and animated attributes and then find that I need to insert 100 frames somewhere in my 5000 frame animation to make space for additional animation. In the past, I've struggled with selecting all objects and all of their keyframes to move them down the timeline as it seems that I always miss some attributes that don't get moved and then things get ugly and I waste a lot of time fixing things.

I feel like there must be a more elegant way to insert a certain number of frames into the timeline easily without worrying that some keyframes will be left behind. I've tried my luck with the dope sheet, but I don't really find it any easier to use than the graph editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Elegant" in this case is in the eye of the beholder.

Effectively what you need to do is move all the keys after a given point by a given amount. The hard part is that moving the keys will change the meaning of the curves: the interpolation is going to change no matter what you do unless you've got locked tangents on both sides of the change.

if you just want to insert keys at a particular point in time, it'll look like this:

```
def move_keys_after(start, time_shift):
    key_string = '%s:' % start
    for curve in cmds.ls(type='animCurve'):
        before =  cmds.keyframe(curve, q=True)
        cmds.keyframe(curve, r = True,  tc = time_shift, t = (key_string,), iub=True)
        after = cmds.keyframe(curve, q=True)
        print curve, before, "->", after


move_keys_after( 10, 20)
```

That example moves *all* of the keys in the scene after time `start` by `time_shift` frames.  If you want to limit this to an object you could get the anim curves from the object directly or use the `animation` flag of the [keyframe command](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/keyframe.html)

Comment: thank you for the script. Too bad a function like this is not built into Maya. Is this MEL script? Because when I put it into the script editor, I get an error message "invalid use of the maya object 'start'". Sorry, I'm not very familiar with MEL script syntax.

Comment: No, this is python.  I'd recommend doing it in Python instead of MEL if you can -- the mel version of this will be much more complex to read and maintain